# Yii2 DateControl: How to set default value (date)

Tags: yii2

I have in *views/example/_form.php* the following date field:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
...
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
...
echo $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DateControl::className(), [
        'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATE,
        // 'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
        // 'value' => date('d.m.Y'),
        // 'value' => time(),
        // 'value' => '02.12.2015',
        // 'value' => '2015-12-02',
        // 'value' => '2015-12-02 00:00:00 0000',
        // 'value' => date('Y-M-d'),
        // 'value' => date('d.M.Y'),
        // 'value' => date('dd.MM.yyyy'),
]);
...
ActiveForm::end();
```

None of my attempts to set the default date was successfull (see the commented lines above). I have always received no error message and no default value. The resulting HTML input field looks always the same (the 'value' is empty):

```
<input type="text" id="yiiversion-date-disp" class="form-control" name="date-yiiversion-date" value="" data-krajee-datecontrol="datecontrol_1e107159" data-datepicker-source="yiiversion-                     date-disp-kvdate" data-datepicker-type="2" data-krajee-kvdatepicker="kvDatepicker_0aa71c62">
```

Configuration in *config/main.php* looks like this:

```
'modules' => [
    'datecontrol' =>  [
        'class' => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',
        'autoWidget' => true,
        'autoWidgetSettings' => [
            'date' => [
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true,
                    'todayHighlight' => true,
                    'todayBtn' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

The dates are displayed as *01.01.2015 ('dd.MM.yyyy')* and saved as *2015-01-01 ('Y-M-d')* - MySQL datatype DATE.

More information:

- https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol
- http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol

Comment: try giving value under options. 'options' => [ 'value' => date('d-M-Y')],

Comment: Try `model->date  = 'date(dateFormat)' `.

Comment: @ck_arjun I tried it, but with no positive result.

Comment: datepicker is working as expected right?? Issue only with setting default ??

Comment: @InsaneSkull I added to the controller : $model->date = date('Y-m-d'); Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @ck_arjun datepicker, displaying and saving the date works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by InsaneSkull the solution is quite simple. I had to add to the correspondig controller only: *$model->date = date('Y-m-d');*

The resulting action could look e.g. like this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new YiiTask();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        $model->date = date('Y-m-d');
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: not working i have passed the value-form controller to the view but still date input is blank

Answer (score 0):

use options

```
echo $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DateControl::className(), [
        'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATE,
        'options'=>[
            'value' => '2015-12-02'
         ]

]);
```